# The opposite of scalar variables

Tags: php, c, terminology

PHP and C use the term "scalar variables".

> Scalar variables are those containing an integer, float, string or boolean. Types array, object and resource are not scalar.

Is there a term that describes the variables that are not scalar?

Comment: do you mean none-scalar ?

Comment: Non-scalar I believe. Though the term "scalar" is not used in C afaik, instead we call those variables primitives, or primitive types.

Comment: In C, there's an *aggregate* type such as structures and arrays.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php scalar types and **compound** types. Notice in PHP, string is also considered a scalar.

Comment: C++ uses the terms **Fundamental Types**, **Compound Types**, and **Classes**. Can't see what terms are used in the C standard document as easily as I can see them in the C+++ standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of the data-type (for PHP, not C):

Most often a scalar type represents a *primitive data type*. Next, to that, you have *composite types* (arrays, objects) and *other types* (resource handles) (this classification of data-types is leaned on [the ones from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)).

In PHP `NULL` is not part of the scalars.

This aligns with the groups given in the [*Types Introduction* in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/language.types.intro):

- *scalar types*: [boolean](http://php.net/language.types.boolean), [integer](http://php.net/language.types.integer), [float](http://php.net/language.types.float), [string](http://php.net/language.types.string)
- *compound types*: [array](http://php.net/language.types.array), [object](http://php.net/language.types.object)
- *special types*: [resource](http://php.net/language.types.resource), [NULL](http://php.net/language.types.null)

And from the PHP manual entry for the [`is_scalar` function](http://php.net/is_scalar):

> Scalar types are those containing an [integer](http://php.net/language.types.integer), [float](http://php.net/language.types.float), [string](http://php.net/language.types.string) or [boolean](http://php.net/language.types.boolean). Types [array](http://php.net/language.types.array), [object](http://php.net/language.types.object) and [resource](http://php.net/language.types.resource) are not scalar.

Comment: Not to mention that `function`/`callback` is actually a datatype these days as well, and would have to come under the category of `special`

Comment: @Mark Baker: No they are not. Those are pseudo-types and not real data-types. For example the *callback* can be a scalar as well as a compound type - it just depends which data-type it is (e.g. string or array).

Answer (score 2):

In C terminology the Standard distinguishes scalar types and "*aggregate and  union types*".

Structure and array types form the aggregate types. An union type is not of  an aggregate type. Arithmetic and pointer types form the scalar types.